# How to get the file location of the current wallpaper file?

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10

I set the wallpaper to a custom image (and forget when and how), and now want to use the current image for further purposes. Where do I find the file?

Am using Gnome 3.34.3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a terminal, do:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

You will get something like `file://path/to/filename`.

Or, equivalently, open `dconf-editor` (install it if you don't have it) and navigate to this key.

Answer (score 4):

You can find it in your .local/share/backgrounds folder located in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Open dconf, and navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri` and you will find a file path.

On my system it was /home/lexible/.cache/gnome-control-center/backgrounds/[hexidecimal string here].